# Como agrupar registros por faixa de horário?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL, que armazena as visitas no meu site, tendo como campos: **id** | **ip** | **data**, sendo a **data** do tipo `DATETIME`.

O que preciso é que separar essas visitas por horários de pico.

Exemplo:

```
Das 10:00 às 12:00 | 500 visitas
Das 14:00 às 16:00 | 800 visitas
```

O que tenho hoje é a lista dos horários e do lado a quantidade de visitas, independente da quantidade.

```
Das 06:00 às 08:00 | 220
Das 08:00 às 10:00 | 410
Das 10:00 às 12:00 | 105
```

Preciso ordenar pelo horário que teve mais visitas, como fazer isso?

O que tenho agora é isso:

```
<?php 
$sel_visitas = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acessos_site"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sel_visitas) >= 1){ 
    $sel_00_06 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acessos_site WHERE TIME(data) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00'");
    $visitas_00_06 = mysql_num_rows($sel_00_06); 
?> 
<table border="0" style="width:940px;"> 
    <tr class="tit"> 
        <td>Horário</td> 
        <td>Visitas</td> 
    <tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Das 00:00 às 06:00</td> 
        <td><?php echo $visitas_00_06;?></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O código que você postou não bate com o que você colocou em "O que tenho hoje é ...".

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar funções do próprio MySQL para tratar(`CASE`), agrupar(`GROUP_BY`) e ordenar os resultados(`ORDER BY`):

```sql
SELECT tempo,count(*) as quantidade
FROM (
  SELECT 
  (CASE
  WHEN DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') > '07:00' 
  && DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') < '09:00' THEN '07h às 09h'
  WHEN DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') > '12:00' 
  && DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') < '14:00' THEN '12h às 14h'
  WHEN DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') > '19:00' 
  && DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') < '21:00' THEN '19h às 21h'
  WHEN DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') > '21:00' 
  && DATE_FORMAT(data, '%H:%i:%s') < '23:00' THEN '21h às 23h'
   ELSE 0 END)
  AS tempo
  FROM base
) as acessos    
GROUP BY tempo
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9207d/25/0)

Utilizei tambem o `DATE_FORMAT` para retornar apenas a hora. E em relaçao ao PHP a extensão `mysql` foi descontinuada, use o [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser descobrir o horário de pico de acordo com todo o histórico de visitas do seu site:

```sql
SELECT
    HOUR(data) AS hora,
    COUNT(*) AS acessos
FROM acessos_site
GROUP BY hora
ORDER BY acessos DESC;
```

Se você quiser descobrir o horário de pico de cada dia:

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR(data) AS ano,
    MONTH(data) AS mes,
    DAYOFMONTH(data) AS dia,
    count(*) AS acessos
FROM acessos_site
GROUP BY ano, mes, dia
ORDER BY acessos DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá acredito que isso resolva para você:

```
SELECT * FROM visitas WHERE HOUR(data) >= 10 and HOUR(data) <= 12;
SELECT COUNT(*) as nVisitas FROM visitas WHERE HOUR(data) >= 10 and HOUR(data) <= 12;
```

De uma testada, caso isso não resolva seu caso volte a postar aqui que tento achar uma outra solução....